# Making data passed to modal usable for further code execution by concatenating to <embed> src string

Tags: php, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, concatenation

I am passing a dynamic string of data to booststrap modal using data-val in an HTML table.

```
<td <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-val="<?php echo $row['order_id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my-modal" data-order-id ="<?php echo $row['order_id']; ?>">Update</button></td>
```

I then have a script which submits the data using class(I don't have to use class here) to the modal.

```
<script>
    $('#my-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
      var myVal = $(event.relatedTarget).data('val');
      //$(this).find("#modal-body").text(myVal);
      $(this).find(".modal-body").text(myVal);
      //$(this).find("<h6></h6>").text(myVal);
      //$( "p" ).find( "span" ).text(myVal);
    });
</script/
```

The modal then displays the string within the class statement as it should.

```
<div class="modal-body">
```

I need to then be able to concatenate the contents of the "class" string into an HTML embed statement within the modal, that then displays a pdf file. I do not know how to "extract" the class "string information" so that I may concatenate it within the src statement. I have tried using h6, p and span options instead of class to no avail.
So, the embed code in the modal should look something like:

```
<embed
                src="https://www.xx-xxxxx.com/image/waybill/ICE000??CLASS STRING??.pdf"
                type="application/pdf"
                frameBorder="0"
                scrolling="auto"
                height="70%"
                width="150%"
            ></embed>
```

As you may see, I have very limited knowledge of JS and JQuery, so any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What "class string" are you talking about here?

Comment: `<td <button` ? Is that a typo introduced here when writing the question or in your actual HTML?

Comment: The button tag also looks badly formed as it appears unclosed after `data-order-id ="<?php echo $row['order_id']; ?>"</td>` ~ there should be a `>` before `</td>`

Comment: Apologies I have corrected the </button> code error.

Comment: @CBroe - my terminology is poor as I am not sure what else to call it. In this case it is the contents of the class "modal-body" which would be <?php echo $row['order_id']; ?>

Comment: Well you have that in `myVal` already, no? So the actual question would now be, how to dynamically insert this into the URL in the `src` attribute of the embed element? I am guessing you know the other, "static" parts of that URL upfront already - so assemble the full, dynamic URL using string concatenation then?

Comment: @CBroe, thanks, that's really my question. I could make the class include the full URL, where it has already concatenated the data, but how to insert this into the src statement. e.g. class modal-body is the full URL. How to include the content of the class into the:- src=??class??

Comment: You should really go read up on some basics, because almost none of the things you refer to as "class" here, are actually named that :-) // You already now about the `find` method - so use that to find the `embed` element within your modal, and then use `attr` to set its new `src` value.

Comment: @CBroe - your advice of targeting the embed element and then setting the attr src value resolved my problem. If you wish to change to an answer I could accept it as chosen answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the value that you want to dynamically insert into the embed URL in `myVal` already.

So the next step would be the select the embed element inside your modal (`find`), and then setting its `scr` attribute to a different value, using `.attr()`, https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1):

In case this could help anybody with a similar problem in the future.
By targeting the embed element and the src attribute as advised, this code worked for me.

```
<script>
    $('#editModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
      var myVal = $(event.relatedTarget).data('val');
      $(this).find('embed').attr("src",myVal);
    });
</script/
```

The concatenated string was created in the data-val within the Button statement.